# Drying a cup on Shabbos with a paper napkin

Tags: halacha, shabbat, cleaning

Is one allowed on Shabbos to dry the inside of a wet cup with a paper napkin, or would this be prohibited because of sechitah?

Comment: Presumably you're mopping up all the water, so I don't see where S'chita comes into it.

Comment: Why would you want to dry a kiddush cup on Shabbos, considering, according to views in the Talmud, you can only make kiddush anyway on diluted wine?;)

Comment: @Loewian that was only said in regard to the wine during the talmudic era, which was stronger than our wine.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons sechitah comes into it because water will necessarily be squeezed out of the paper napkin that is being used to dry the wet cup.

Comment: @candyman how could wine have been stronger than our wine? Yeast die at ~14% alcohol

Comment: @do Unless user17456 meant by stronger that it was thicker, sweeter and more concentrated...

Comment: @user17456 If water's being squeezed out you're doing the drying wrong - the idea is that the water goes into the paper.

Comment: @Loewian Do we not have concentrated, sweet, thick wine available? Have you never had a glass of Manischewitz's finest?

Answer (score 5):

There are two *melachoth* that could be violated during an act of squeezing - *dosh*/*mefarek* (extracting) or *melabein* (cleaning).  With regard to the former, your point is to absorb the moisture into the napkin, not to release it.  If some was unintentionally extracted as well, that would be considered a *davar she'eino mithkavein* (unintentional) and therefore also permitted (even according to those who hold one would violate *dosh*/*mefarek* for desirable re-extraction of an artificially absorbed substance).   With regard to *melabein*, the napkin typically is not desirably cleaner as a result of the drying of the cup.  See, e.g., Shulchan Arukh OC 302:12, Mishna Berura 302:59, and Shemirath Shabbath Kehilchatha 12:19,21, all cited [here](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Melabain).

If one did indeed intend/desire to clean a dirty cloth in the process, that would be forbidden. Similarly, if there is a likelihood that one would subsequently wring out and clean the drying cloth, there may be a rabbinic prohibition on using it. See e.g. Shulchan Arukh OC 302:11; Mishna Berura 302:46 and 302:57; and Shemirath Shabbath Kehilchatha 14:29, all cited [here](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Melabain).

Comment: Sources for this would help a lot. Re - "With regard to libun, the napkin typically is not desirably cleaner as a result of the drying of the cup" I think you meant that the **cup** should not be cleaner, not the napkin. Even with that, most cups have a bit of wine in it. The napkin gets the wine stain but the cup is almost definitely cleaner. So, based on that, how can one clean the cup with a napkin, unless you rinse the cup in water first?

Comment: @danf *libun* is an issue when cleaning cloth; one is allowed to clean metal, ceramic, glass etc. (for shabbos purposes).

Comment: good answer, may be worth pointing out that it is not a psik reisha vis-a-vis the napkin.

Comment: I didn't know that. You may want to mention in your answer (assuming my correct understanding) that you can use a paper napkin but not a cloth one.

Comment: @DanF You can use a cloth one as well.  The napkin does not typically get any cleaner.  But I mention that if that was a desire as well, it would be forbidden.